# Why doesn't Hiashi Hyuga use the curse mark during the Fourth Great Shinobi War?

Tags: naruto

During the Fourth Great Shinobi war, Hizashi Hyuga is reanimated by Kabuto and is forced to fight against Hiashi. Why doesn't Hiashi use the [curse mark](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hy%C5%ABga_Main_Family's_Juinjutsu) and destroy Hizashi's brain cells?

Comment: It's not really his brain since Kabuto is using another person's body, so I don't think it would affect him.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru But during Mifune vs Hanzo, we saw that Hanzo was using his own brain until Kabuto tried to take over (but failed because his body was paralysed by  salamander poison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, really. Because destroying his brain means nothing. Why? Because an edo tensei-ed person will [rebuilt any broken body part](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Enhancements) after awhile, which is why the only way to fight them is to seal them.